# Does anyone know how to use a Bazaar repository with TeamCity?

Tags: version-control, teamcity, continuous-integration, bazaar

I am using Bazaar for some projects and generally like it. I recently started looking into integrating it with TeamCity and thought it would be quite easy until I found that it wasn't supported out of the box.

I have installed the bzr4j (https://launchpad.net/bzr4j) plugin and found that it did show Bazaar as an option when configuring the VCS root but whenever I select it, it just hangs on the rotating progress indicator.

I am using the latest version of TeamCity but noticed that this plugin hasn't been updated for a few years. Is it a realistic objective to get this working or am I wasting my time?

Alan